# Run animation when element is visible - custom javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website with few animation, below is the piece of javascript and css which is revealing image from left to right

```js
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $('.mask').width(i + "%");
    i++;
    if (i == 101) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    }
    }, 20);
```

```css
    .mask {
      background:white;
      max-width: 640px;
      z-index:1;
      height: 426px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .img {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="mask">
    <div class="img">
    <img src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

and then an javascript which reveals image from right to left.

```js
var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $('.mask3').css({ left: -i + "%" });
    i++;
    if (i === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    }
    }, 20);
```

```css
    .wrapper {
      width: 640px;
      height: 430px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .mask3 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background:white;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index:1;
    }
    
    .img {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index:0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="mask3">
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now I am trying to load this animation only when div is being displayed, or user scroll down to specific div, and then the animation shall roll back.

I tried few of the scripts, but all of them guided to use if else statement although I am not able to pick anything which is working, can someone please help me out on this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very rough answer, but you can do this if you want. You will still need to work on your animation function more to make it hide and then display based on how you want it to be.

```
var elem = $('.img'); //use a better identifier like an id.
var counter = 0
elem.hide();

function myAnimation() {
    elem.show();
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $('.mask').width(i + "%");
    i++;
    if (i == 101) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    }
    }, 20);
    counter++;
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    if ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop) && counter < 1) {
        myAnimation();
    }
});
```

The counter is basically to animate it once, because you will trigger this animation on every scroll.

Comment: Hey @Abba, this is somewhat working, but as I mentioned in my question as I am not that confident in jQuery, and I have few doubts.
The image is by default visible and when user scrolls down to element it starts the animation which seems to be somewhat weird.
What I need is that initially the image should be hidden and when the user scrolls down the animation starts, and it should smoothly roll back when the user scrolls down further or up or leave the frame.

Any help is appreciated, I am stuck on this one from last 48 hours.

Comment: I used CSS to make initial width to 0 for my mask class, and that sorted out one of the issue, just need to roll back on leaving the frame.

Comment: You can add an elem.hide() at the top of your JS code, and then call elem.show() inside your animation function. I edited the code to show you.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your revert, I tried few lines of code along with css and it is working as I stated in my previous reply.
But now when I am trying to repeat the animation on other elements, it's not working. Hence I can use it once on single page. Any idea how to get it working for multiple elements, and smoothly revert back the animation if user scrolls out of the visible element.
I am trying but to no avail.